# Support for OGC API - Records in MetaSearch

Tags: qgis, metadata, owslib, ogc-api

I’ve been trying to access [OGC API - Records through the MetaSearch Catalog](https://qgis.org/en/site/forusers/visualchangelog324/index.html#id50) of the latest release of QGIS (QGIS 3.24 ‘Tisler’) but I ended up with the following issue:

```
Search error: {
    "code": "InvalidParameterValue",
    "description": "unknown query parameter: startindex"
}
```

While I can get consistent responses from the service description and the API, I can't load the associated information.

Has anyone experienced a similar problem?

The endpoint I am trying to access is: https://demo.pygeoapi.io/master/collections/dutch-metadata

I’m on Windows 10 using a version 3.24 of QGIS with OWSLib 0.25.0.

Comment: You could try with other implementations:  https://github.com/opengeospatial/ogcapi-records/blob/master/implementations.md

Answer (score 0):

Changelog for OWSLib, which is used under the hood by QGIS MetaSearch, shows recent removal of support for `startindex` in place of  `offset`.

ref: https://github.com/geopython/OWSLib/commit/16ba31af36d155d1a89007ead2792218dcbb4fa7

I'm not sure whether `startindex` should ever have been expected to be supported, it was removed from OGC API Features (core) ~ https://github.com/opengeospatial/ogcapi-features/issues/75.

So the issue is I assume that the API instances, either never supported startindex, or have been updated to not support it, and  the metasearch plugin (or your version of it) is not yet using the latest OWSLib libraries.

As it says on the plugin page:

> The OGC API - Records standard is currently in development and the current timeline for a public RFC by OGC is Q1 2022. This we ask you to take note of the draft status of the specification so you are aware that the specification may change a bit more over the next few months

Things are still evolving...

Comment: Version 3.25 of QGIS integrates the latest version of OWSLib (0.25.0) and the changes have been made on the above-mentioned endpoint:

https://demo.pygeoapi.io/master/collections/dutch-metadata/items?offset=5&limit=2

So the changes in my opinion would have to be made in the source code:

I think the 'startindex' parameter should be replaced by 'offset' in this line of code:

https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/4539f276fa6b61d8f018e6f33deabcc8c3194d3e/python/plugins/MetaSearch/search_backend.py#L198

Does this make sense to you?

Answer (score 0):

The issue should be solved with this PR:

https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/pull/47724

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).